# Qt Creator very slow due to constant indexing with clangd

Tags: parsing, indexing, clang, qt-creator, clangd

I use Qt Creator 7.0.2 for a mixed C/C+ project using CMake 3.20.6 (and Ninja as a generator) (and MinGW 7.30 64-bits as a main compiler), and it has been recently very slow due to constant indexing. It says almost at all times inthe bottom right "Indexing  with clangd" and says it has anywhere between 1 and 4 files to index. This makes everything slow or frozen as it consumes a lot of CPU and seems to be blocking for everything in Qt Creator. This wasn't the case before, or ever in previous versions.

Any tips or hints as to what could cause this ? I can deactivate clangd parsing/indexing, but then I get no auto-complete or other project-parsing/indexing-dependent functionalities.

Comment: Are you by chance seeing this when editing a header file? Clangd reparses files that include the header file (though I believe only open ones) after modifications to a header, so that may be what you're seeing. Other than that, for further diagnosis I would suggest sharing [clangd logs](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#gathering-logs) (for bonus points, indicate the range of timestamps in the log during which the editor was frozen).

Comment: Why not updating to the most recent version (9.0.2), see if the issue persists?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Qt Creator 10.

Lowering clang priority and limiting the threads it is using solved the issue for me :

[image]

Alternatively, you can completely disable clangd with the top checkbox. This also solves the issue.